# how to copy file from local to sharepoint site usins SSIS Or Script Task of ssis

Tags: c#, ssis

I tried with the C# code mention in one of the site and used Microsoft.Sharepoint.client dll in refrence ,still I am getting and red underline on SPSite and SPWeb.
Can you please help where I am doing mistake or any alternative way to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfs09.png)

Answer (score 0):

The couple places I have a need for this, I just use a data flow to export a file to the windows explorer path of the sharepoint site folder I need the file in.